# Eclipse plugin - find out last exception

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse plugin and I would like to be able to find out about exceptions and errors the user encounters.

For starters, how can I find out information about the last run time exception that occurred, let's say when a user clicks a button? By information I mean the exception type and the file and line where it was thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Any exception logged to Eclipse is saved in the workspace's .log file located at `WORKSPACE_DIR\.metadata\.log`

You can also inspect this log visually by using the Eclipse `Error Log` view.
To open the `Error Log`, select `Window->Show View->Error Log`

Comment: Thanks but I am looking mainly for runtime errors, which are not shown in the error log. Your answer did point me towards getting the console output, which seems like what I want to do.

Comment: The console output is not saved, unless you explicitly log it with the Eclipse logging infrastructure.